# How to test a component that renders children as props in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test if a given component renders as many children as it receives. For now, it renders only two components. I'm stuck as I'm new to unit testing. Here's what I tried:

**Component.js:**

```
const Component = ({ children }) => {
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};
```

**Component.test.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Component from './Component';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
import ChildComponent2 from './ChildComponent';

it('show a ChildComponent component', () => {
    const wrapped = shallow(<Component children />);

    expect(wrapped.find(ChildComponent).length).toEqual(1)
});

it('show a ChildComponent2 component', () => {
    const wrapped = shallow(<Component children />);

    expect(wrapped.find(ChildComponent2).length).toEqual(1)
});
```

Comment: I leave an upvote but I don't understand your question. what do you expect?

Comment: what is the role of the `ChildComponent` in your test file? I am asking because your `Component` is rendering those component. is it?

Answer (score 1):

1. when you use shallow rendering `shallow` then you will not render children so this test cannot work. Your intention is to check for the children.
2. When you render `<Component/>` you want to actually pass those children

```
<Component>
    <ChildComponent />
    <ChildComponent2 />
</Component>
```